# iOS - segue from alert view is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a segue that I want to be preformed when I push the Manual Entry and Scan Tag buttons on my AlertView.

```
@implementation triageViewController
- (IBAction)addNew:(id)sender {

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add A New Entry"
                                                message:@"Choose a way to add a new entry."
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Manual Entry", @"Scan Tag", nil];
  [alert show];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  if (buttonIndex != alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"manual" sender: self];
}
  if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"scan" sender: self];
  }
}
```

(I realize this would probably make the cancel button preform a segue right now, but i'm more concerned with making it work)

I have the two segues in my storyboard, going from a UITabViewController to two different UIViewControllers. neither of these are being called, so when I tap them. I tried using both push and modal segues, but neither one was working.

I also tried the if/else statement like so:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"manual" sender: self];

}
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"scan" sender: self];
}
}
```

But this is not working either.

Could someone help me figure out what is going wrong? Again in case I was unclear, I want to preform a segue from a UIAlertView pop-up located on a UITabBarController to two separate UIViewControllers.
Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Does your code pass the `if` tests?

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint in clickedButtonAtIndex and debug it? Does it bypass the if statements? Or does it call performSegue? Are the segue's named correctly and are they connected directly to the TriageViewController? Want to post a photo of that part of your storyboard?

Comment: Hey guys, the segue isn't working. I realized I simply forgot to set the delegate to `self`, as what @Miron answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `UIAlertView` has a `delegate` of `nil` so your function is never being called. Set that to `self` and then in your view controller's header make sure you're implementing the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.

Comment: darn, not sure why I didn't notice that, thanks for saving me the headache.